# Burpsuite certificate

Tags: http-proxy

When I try to configure burp with firefox and when I tried to launch a website in firefox after setting the network for burp proxy. The site is not getting launched and there is no burp certificate in firefox. Will that be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

For Browser setting:

1.Download `Foxyproxy`.

2.click option and then add button.

3.set as `Ip-127.0.0.1 port-8080`

4.Make sure that proxy type as http and not https.

5.save and make active.

For Burp:

1.Goto proxy->options.

2.set as `127.0.0.1:8080`

3.And make sure that is running.

1.Go to http://burp and download the certiicate.

2.Go to firefox options and search for certificate options.

3.Place the certificate in the authorities.

4.If want to confirm whether it had installed then search the certificate as            portswigger.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are asking just about **certificate**.

But I will write down all **3 step** in case anyone else read it and any one step of the 3 steps is missing. For certificate skip Step 1 & 2 and please refer to Step 3.

1. **Start Burp and set its proxy.**
2. **Set your network/ browser proxy.**
3. **Install/Add Burp Suite certificate to your trusted certificates store.**

Now if your dealing with only ***http request***, you can skip the third step.
3rd step is only required for ***https requests***.

**Step 1:**

- Run Burp Suite and start a temporary project.
- Go to Proxy tab and options tab inside proxy and check if the proxy
  is set and on. For starter its set to 127.0.0.1:8080
- Go to Intercept sub-tab inside proxy tab and turn the intercept off
  for now.

**Step 2:**

- Open your browser/ computer's proxy setting and add the same address
  that you set in Burp Suite.(127.0.0.1:8080) and save it.
- Now your network is routing through Burp Suite at 127.0.0.1:8080 and
  you may see all the http traffic in HTTP history sub-tab inside proxy
  tab.

**Coming to the Step 3 The Certificate:**

- Hit the proxy Url (127.0.0.1:8080) in the browser and Burp Suite will
  create your a certificate attached on the page. Download the
  certificate.
- Now go to browser settings and search for manage certificates option
  in security.
- Select the trusted root certification authority tab, click import.
- Browse to where you download the certificate and follow the dialog
  until finish. Your Certificate is added.
- Restart Burp Suite and Browser.
- Now you can successfully capture https requests in HTTP history
  sub-tab of proxy tab. Also you can enable intercept before initiating
  request to capture.

---

[You can also go through a detailed blog post by Howard Poston here](https://resources.infosecinstitute.com/intercepting-https-traffic-with-burp-suite/)

---

Comment: Thank you Abdul for taking time to respond